# Use Integration by Parts to find $\int \cos x\cdot e^x\;dx$

Tags: calculus

Use Integration by Parts to find  $\int \cos x\cdot e^x\;dx$.

How is this done? Please, feel sorry for me and help me out. Today has been a very bad day and I can't concentrate very much on this problem because my cat died. Can you help me?

Comment: Is this the 7th or the 9th time that happens?

Comment: At least show *some* work you have tried before asking for help. You want to integrate a product of two functions by parts and you can't try something yourself first?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it The OP appears to be guilt-tripping others into doing his or her work for them.

Comment: No I am not tricking anyone

Comment: @Pp.. what do you mean?

Comment: I know I have to use uv - Integrate u dv/dx dx

Comment: @User It is just a pedantic joke. A reference to the saying that cats have $9$ lives (or 7 in some other cases).

Comment: @Pp.. Ah I see. Never heard that before

Comment: @RonGordon With google, it takes less time to find a duplicate than to type a custom close reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In integration by parts

$$\int f(x)g'(x)\text{d}x=f(x)g(x)-\int f'(x)g(x)\text{d}x$$

there is a factor $g'(x)$ which we integrate to $g(x)$ and a factor $f(x)$ which we differentiate to $f'(x)$.

Let's take $g'(x)=e^x$ and therefore $g(x)=e^x$ and for the role of $f(x)$ we take first $\cos(x)$ and latter $\sin(x)$ for a second application of integration by parts.

$$\int\cos(x)e^x\text{d}x=\cos(x)e^x+\int\sin(x)e^x\text{d}x=\cos(x)e^x+\left(\sin(x)e^x-\int\cos(x)e^x\text{d}x\right)$$

Therefore

$$\int\cos(x)e^x\text{d}x=\frac{\cos(x)e^x+\sin(x)e^x}{2}$$

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer , thank you very much for your kind support.